# How to detect two finger touch: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have touchMove event handler.

I am trying to access event object or to be the more specific number of touches on display.

```
<div className={"LeafletMap"} onTouchMove={(e) => this.handleMapMove(e)}  onTouchStart={this.handleMapTouch} >
....
```

Then I access event in handler method

```
handleMapMove = (e) => {
   console.log(e);
   ...
};
```

In the console, I can see

```
Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, isPropagationStopped: ƒ, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: SyntheticTouchEvent
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

How Can I access `[[Target]] object` in an example, or to be more specific, **I need to notify the user to use two fingers to move map instead of one.**

Comment: `console.log(e.target)` ??

Comment: But this returns HTML to element which is clicked, I need to return number of touches

Comment: means, how many times that element has been touched, correct?

Comment: Yes, or to be more specific. I need to notify the user to use two fingers to move map instead of one.

Comment: You are my hero of the day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `touches` property of the touch event, it will contain all the touch points available.

Like this:

```
handleMapMove = (e) => {
    console.log(e.touches);
};
```

As per **[MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/touches)**:

> A TouchList listing all the Touch objects for touch points that are
>   currently in contact with the touch surface, regardless of whether or
>   not they've changed or what their target element was at touchstart
>   time.
>
> This property is Read only .
>
> Could be thought of **how many separate fingers** are able to be
>   identified to be touching the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this:

```
let target = e.target || e.srcElement;
```

This will give you a regular DOMNode though.

You can call regular DOMNode function on it though, so the following would return the id of the target node:

```
target.getAttribute('id')
```

Take a look at the documentation: [target - mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

## Edit based on your comments

To get the number of clicks save the number of clicks in your React component's state and use that.

Take a look at the following example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0,
      show: true
    };
  }

  IncrementItem = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
  }
  DecreaseItem = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks - 1 });
  }
  ToggleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.IncrementItem}>Click to increment by 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.DecreaseItem}>Click to decrease by 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.ToggleClick}>
          { this.state.show ? 'Hide number' : 'Show number' }
        </button>
        { this.state.show ? <h2>{ this.state.clicks }</h2> : '' }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

which I took from: [medium.com](https://medium.com/@aghh1504/2-increment-and-decrease-number-onclick-react-5767b765103c)

## Based on yet more information added through comments..

You seem to want to get the number of fingers on the display, you don't need the target event for that you need "[touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)".

To check whether two fingers have clicked you can use the following code:

```
handleMapMove = (e) => {
   if(e.touches.length == 2){
     console.log("yay, two finger press")
   }
};
```